# R simulate inverse normal distribution

Tags: r, distribution

I'm wondering is there any function in R that we can use to simulate a distribution opposite to the normal distribution? 
by opposite i mean instead of starting from a low value and gradually increasing to a peak and then gradually decreasing , i want this distribution to start from a high value then gradually decreasing to a small value and then increasing to initial value.
thanks.

Comment: How about defining your function g(.) as 1 - normaldist() ?

Comment: no It won't work Drik since i want the density of the distribution to follow this shape ...

Comment: You need to have a better idea of what your shape "needs" to look like (and why). Somewhere between an inverse delta function and the BathtubFunction is what you're after, but that's a large space.

Comment: Do you have a finite domain? The normal is defined on the whole real line, but you'll be hard-pressed to define a valid pdf that increases as it approaches +/-`Inf`.

Comment: yes, domain is finite.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a probability distribution that starts high, goes low and ends high then try `beta` distribution with `alpha` = `beta` = `0.5`. In R:

```
rb <- rbeta(1000, 0.5, 0.5)
hist(rb)
```

It produces values between `(0,1)`, you might want to scale and/or shift it appropriately.

Comment: thanks, do we need to set the seed in a specific way for beta distribution? since i used set.seed(40) but it is changing in consecutive repetitions.

Comment: you need to `set.seed` once (in the beginning) if you want to reproduce the result. Otherwise there is no need to `set.seed`. R will internally set the seed based on system time/processID.

Comment: yes i want to re-produce the result. that's why i'm using the set.seed but results are changing each time i run the experiment :-/ ....

Comment: here is my code   `seed.set(40)`
`rb <- rbeta(40, 0.5, 0.5)`
`table(cut(rb,10))`
`plot(table(cut(rb,10)))`

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

    > set.seed(40)
    > rb1 <- rbeta(40,0.5,0.5)
    > 
    > set.seed(40)
    > rb2 <- rbeta(40,0.5,0.5)
    > 
    > identical(rb1,rb2)
    [1] TRUE

Comment: if you set seed once & call `rbeta(40,0.5,0.5)` twice then ofcourse results will be different.